# DrawingBrush always rendered on CPU (not GPU)?

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml, drawingbrush

I'm struggling with some WPF performance issues. The Ants profiler and dotTrace both show that all the time is deep in the WPF internals. I have a number of DrawingBrush objects presently in use. The old WpfPerf.exe shows that my DrawingBrush objects are being rendered on the CPU instead of the GPU. Is there something I can do to change that? Below is an example of one. Why does it render CPU-side?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="mapViewModel:ObstacleVM" x:Key="ObstacleShapeTemplate">
    <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeOutlineBrush}" StrokeThickness="{Binding WorldAndScreen.MetersPerPixel, Converter={StaticResource Multiplier}, ConverterParameter=1}" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat">
        <Path.Fill>
            <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                <DrawingBrush.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding WorldAndScreen.MetersPerPixel, Converter={StaticResource Multiplier}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
                </DrawingBrush.Transform>
                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeFillBrush}">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                        <PathGeometry>
                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <LineSegment Point="1,0" />
                                                <LineSegment Point="1,1" />
                                                <LineSegment Point="0,1" />
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeOutlineBrush}">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                        <PathGeometry>
                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                <LineSegment Point="0,.33" />
                                                <LineSegment Point="1,.33" />
                                                <LineSegment Point="1,0" />
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathGeometry>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            </DrawingBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="{Binding Figures, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultFigures}}" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicResource` ?

Comment: In fact the GPU used here is an integrated part into CPU, not the dedicated GPU (which is turned on and used by such as 3D games ...). So I doubt that there is some misreading here. To know the name of the integrated GPU, you can try running ***dxdiag.exe*** (Run > dixdiag). Normally the dedicated GPU won't never be shown there (only the integrated GPU is shown).

Comment: That's why you have integrated GPU on your CPU to take the load of External GPU and let it run expensive tasks like 3D games. If I remember correctly this feature depends on your chipset of your mother board.

Comment: I just tried changing all the colors to be hard-coded, and WpfPerf still shows these items as rendered by the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading around further, I found some sources suggesting the use of VisualBrish instead. Indeed, I tried this and it seems to fix it (again, according to WpfPerf.exe).

```
<DataTemplate DataType="mapViewModel:ObstacleVM" x:Key="ObstacleShapeTemplate">
    <Path Stroke="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeOutlineBrush}" StrokeThickness="{Binding WorldAndScreen.MetersPerPixel, Converter={StaticResource Multiplier}, ConverterParameter=1}" StrokeLineJoin="Bevel" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat">
        <Path.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
                <VisualBrush.Transform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="{Binding WorldAndScreen.MetersPerPixel, Converter={StaticResource Multiplier}, ConverterParameter=5}" />
                </VisualBrush.Transform>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Image Stretch="None">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <DrawingImage>
                                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <DrawingGroup.Children>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeFillBrush}">
                                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                                        <PathGeometry>
                                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                <LineSegment Point="1,0" />
                                                                <LineSegment Point="1,1" />
                                                                <LineSegment Point="0,1" />
                                                            </PathFigure>
                                                        </PathGeometry>
                                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="{DynamicResource Mobius.UI.Resources.Colors.ObstacleShapeOutlineBrush}">
                                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                                                        <PathGeometry>
                                                            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                                                <LineSegment Point="0,.33" />
                                                                <LineSegment Point="1,.33" />
                                                                <LineSegment Point="1,0" />
                                                            </PathFigure>
                                                        </PathGeometry>
                                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            </GeometryDrawing>
                                        </DrawingGroup.Children>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            </DrawingImage>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Path.Fill>
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" Figures="{Binding Figures, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultFigures}}" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</DataTemplate>
```